# District 9 - References to Apartheid

Tags: historical-accuracy, district-9

How far can the character Wikus be related to that of Biko, and his role to abolish apartheid?

I've recently realized the similar phonetics of the name, so it rang a bell and the question immediately arose.

Comment: Who is biko????

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your parallel is slightly off. It's not Biko that Wikus is related to but Biko's friend, Donald Woods from "*Cry Freedom*".

Both Wikus and Woods were initially of the governing race, and both started with adversarial relationship to Biko/alien known as Christopher Johnson, only later to turn into friends.